# libGDX AppWarp integration problem

Tags: android, libgdx

I have tried to use up `AppWarp`'s old `SuperJumper` as a sample to create an up to date project from it with `Gradle`. Maybe it is good for learning. So, I have downloaded project from `GitHub`(https://github.com/SauravGShephertz/libgdxMultiplayerSuperJumper) as zip and started to build a new `Gradle` based `libGDX` project from it.
Here you can see actual state: https://github.com/kovacsa91/superjumper

I have some errors with following lines.

```
com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.command.*;
```

Maybe it cannot found needed `JAR` file(s)? How should be it placed? Can you please check it out? Code was separated between project folders inside the main `libGDX` project.